# How to use 全体 correctly

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between:

> a) 町全体
>   b) 町の全体
>   c) 全体の町

The intended meaning is "The whole town".

How do I decide which is the correct way to use 全体? I'm guessing there are other words for which the same principles will apply.

P.S. 町 might be a bad choice of noun because I think 町全体 is a word by itself. If so, please replace with another noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a and b are the same meaning. Howevre I think a is a little bit more common. c is unnatural.

全体 modyfies a noun before 全体 as a meaning of "whole". It isn't used such as 全体の家がお菓子で出来ている but 家全体がお菓子で出来ている(The whole house is made of sweets).